# What's the differences between images/ and ./images/?

Tags: path

In fact, it seems to start both from the current page path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a subtle one which is only relevant if multiple search paths exist (like for executables, see `$PATH`).

For example, you can start a local executable with `./filename`, but not with `filename`, as the latter makes (most?) shells search in the paths specified by `$PATH` and not the current working directory.

In a context of URLs, there is no real difference. One should note though, that relative paths are a common attack vector on web applications (escaping the DocumentRoot using ../).

Comment: The question seems to be in regards to URI/URLs. AFAIK there is no difference at all in that context but a nagging part of me says it must be in the spec for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

For directories one would imagine nothing. The PATH variable would not come into the picture as a directory is not a command the shell needs to search.

On the side note here is an interesting page to know more about "./" : http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html